# Join table with itself

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Im trying to join a table with itself.

But get the following error

```
SQL> select a.bookid, b.auname
2  from book_author a, book_author b
3  where a.bookid = b.auname;
where a.bookid = b.auname
             *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The table im trying to join is:

```
create table book_author
(Auname varchar2(15),
bookid number(5),
```

For each bookid, I want to list bookid and each author (column 2) with his/her coauthors (column3) 
I want to do this using virtual copies of BOOK_AUTHOR.
My desired output looks like this.

```
Bookid       Author  Coauthor
1101         Dilbert Emerson
1101         Dilbert Sartre
1101         Emerson Dilbert
1101         Emerson Sartre
1101         Sartre  Dilbert
1101         Sartre  Emeson

    (note Dilbert Dilbert should not appear)



SQL> select * from book_author
2  order by bookid;

AUNAME              BOOKID
--------------- ----------
Emerson               1101
Sartre                1101
Dilbert               1101
Sartre                1102
Axel                  1102
Marquez               1103
Breese                1103
Young                 1104
Groom                 1104
Young                 1105
Blake                 1105
Julian                1105
Verde                 1105
Scott                 1105
Black                 1106
Sartre                1106
Simon                 2007
Emerson               2007
Pell                  2007
Rogers                2008
Sartre                2008
Codd                  2008
Young                 2008
Lamont                2010
Fellows               2011
Modiano               2011
Poe                   2222
Modiano               2222
Null                  2229
```

Comment: First, you're trying to compare a `varchar` with a `number`... Second, I see only two columns, what is "column 3" ?

Comment: How to differentiate between author and co-author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to join the table on the `bookid`, you don't want to compare a `bookid` (a numeric column) to an `auname` (a string column).

Something like

```
select a.bookid, a.auname, b.auname
  from book_author a, 
       book_author b
 where a.bookid = b.bookid
   and a.auname != b.auname;
```

Comment: This only makes two columns. I have updated the question with the format of the output im looking for.

Comment: @JacobLindbergSørensen - Then add a.auname to the select list.  I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. The last problem i'm facing is that I only want to see authors who have worked togehter paired like the example I gave. Right now I get all the possible combination of author and coauthor.

Answer (score 1):

Justin Cave got the correct answer. As an addition: ORA-01722: invalid number means that you mix number and varchar columns in one expression. If you don't explicitly say what you want, Oracle will use implicit conversion rules. In this case Oracle tries to convert b.auname to number because you said to compare it with number value.

Most often it's an error, but seldom it's what you want. If so, you should explicitly say what Oracle should do:

```
where to_char(a.bookid) = b.auname
```